# Android silly ui problem

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

I'm new on Android and I have a silly problem with my application design.

My problem is that I want to make a grid as shown in this example http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html
but I want to create a texbox below the grid and a button after the grid. The textbox has to be always at the top and the button always at the bottom. I have done this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/textView1" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20px" 
    android:text="@string/intro" 
    android:layout_marginTop="20px" 
    android:textSize="35px">
</TextView>
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridView1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
</GridView>
<Button 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/Button_create" 
    android:textSize="18px">
    android:id="@+id/button1">
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

But with this code I have the textbox at the top but not the button at the bottom always. It appears when the grid finish. Also I noticed that in the example there're 2 o 3 columns inside the grid as I want but with this code it only appears one and I do not know why.

Could you help me?

PS. For who will edit the code zone, could you explain me what I have to put when a line ends but it continues the code? Thanks and sorry for your time editing my post

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by "when a line ends and continues code." There is helpful information for the markdown editor though, a little orange question mark above the editor that links to: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help hope that helps.

Comment: I mean after the fist line when it ends, what do i should put to continue all the design of code until the last line of code? Because I press add code and I paste all and the design of code was only in the fist line as you saw.

Comment: Ahh okay, well a good way to format it is to place all of your code in the editor, then select the code and press the `{}` button on the editor to indent the code effectively marking it as code, this will also take care of adding in extra lines separating it from previous text where needed. I would highly recommend to go through the markdown help though and get yourself acquainted.

Answer (score 0):

You should put an `android:layout_gravity` value of e.g. 1 to the `GridView` which you have determined to fill the height of the parent and then for the Button, put value of 0.5.